# Select entre 2 tabelas

Tags: mysql

Com base nas tabelas abaixo e passando a 'dataInicio' e 'dataFim', seria possível com apenas um Select selecionar da Tabela Veiculo só os veículos que não estão na Tabela Reserva?
Estou estudando Inner Join, mas não tenho ideia se isso é possível.

```
Tabela Veiculo
--------------
idVeiculo
nomeVeiculo


Tabela Reserva
--------------
idVeiculo
dataInicio
dataFim
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira coisa a se fazer é criar uma chave para relação entre as 2 tabelas, após isso, ficaria assim por exemplo:

```
SELECT v.nomeVeiculo FROM VEICULO v
INNER JOIN RESERVA r on v.id not in r.veiculo_id;
```

Comment: Obrigado.
Segue a logica final.

 SELECT * FROM veiculo WHERE idVeiculo NOT IN (SELECT veiculo_idVeiculo FROM reservas  WHERE dataIni BETWEEN '".$dataini."' AND '".$datafim."' OR dataFim BETWEEN '".$dataini."' AND '".$datafim."');